# Autofac filters for specific 'async' action in a controller not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, autofac, webapi2

I have a Controller with an async Action. I would like to register a ActionFiler (one that implements IAutofacActionFilter, My code is based on Web API 2, using the Autofac Web API intergration module) for that specific 'async' action in that controller. Following are the snippets I tried and it didn't work. But Synchronous actions do work as mentioned in the Autofac guideline documents.

Tried a few way of specifying the asyn action in the 'Register' configuration but nothing worked. Please refer to the snippets below for tried code.

```
builder.RegisterWebApiFilterProvider(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
builder.Register(componentContext => new RequestLatencyTrackerActionFilter())
    .AsWebApiActionFilterFor<>((actionSelector) => Task.Run<IHttpActionResult>(() => actionSelector.GetMyActionAsync(default(string)))))
    .InstancePerApiRequest();
```

Or,

```
builder.Register(componentContext => new RequestLatencyTrackerActionFilter())
    .AsWebApiActionFilterFor<>((actionSelector) => actionSelector.GetMyActionAsync(default(string)).Wait()))
    .InstancePerApiRequest();
```

A 'Non-async' action works,

```
builder.Register(componentContext => new RequestLatencyTrackerActionFilter())
    .AsWebApiActionFilterFor<>((actionSelector) => actionSelector.GetMyNonAsyncAction(default(string))))
    .InstancePerApiRequest();
```

Are registrations for async actions supported in the Autofac Web API integration modules?

Comment: You might have found a bug! I don't see that we've tested things with async WebAPI actions. [You might need to file an issue.](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac.WebApi/issues)

Comment: @TravisIllig: I have opened an issue: https://github.com/autofac/Autofac.WebApi/issues/49
Thanks !